# JLabel added to JPanel not displayed

Tags: java, swing

i have been trying to display a JLabel added to a JPanel with no sucess for some time now.
Main program :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int screenWidth = 5000;
        //int screenWidth = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(screenWidth);

        JLabel header = new JLabel("Choisissez un nombre");
        header.setBounds(100,100,screenWidth-100,40);
        header.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,40));
        
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBounds(100,140,screenWidth-100,100);
        
        JLabel desc = new JLabel("entrez un nombre entre 1 et 100 : ");
        desc.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,40));
        
        panel1.add(desc);
        frame.add(header);      
        frame.add(panel1);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

`MyFrame` class :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    MyFrame(int screenWidth){
        this.setSize(screenWidth/5,screenWidth/10);
        this.setTitle("Le juste nombre");
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's utterly wrong to null layoutManager

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem wasn't related to my use of `this.setLayout(null)`, it was because of `panel1.setBounds(100,140,screenWidth-100,100);` the panel was overflowing outside the frame and because `desc` was being rendered in the center of `panel1` it was being rendered outside the frame.
**the solution :**
replace : `panel1.setBounds(100,140,screenWidth-100,100);`
by : `panel1.setBounds(100,140,frame.getWidth()-100,100);`

Comment: Using _Absolute Positioning_ is poison. It is more trouble than it was worth. The problem you described in your question occurred for the the reason MadProgrammer explained to you in his answer. When you use a _Layout Manager_, you delegate the placement of the component to it. This way, you don't have to bother in specifying the location of the component. It will be time worth spent to take some time to learn how they work and even setting layout to null as you did. The "fix" here is just a band aid...

Comment: Why _Absolute Positioning_ is a bad idea? For starters, when you resize your GUI (i.e. to view in different screen sizes, your GUI will look like crap. Guaranteed. In contrast, when you select the right Layout Manager for the job (i.e. use `GridLayout` build a chess board), things like a resize is handled by the layout manager beautifully.

Comment: i know absolute positioning is a bad idea that is a well known thing in all fields where graphics and computers are used, but that wasn't my question or my concern for the moment, i wanted to understand what i did wrong in my code, so his answer is valuable in other aspects but not in answering my question

Comment: one reason he listed was wrong "When you call setVisible on the frame, one of the things it's going to do is is run a layout pass, since the frame is still using a BorderLayout at this point," while setVisible was set after i set the layout manager to null not before, so at the point where setVisible is set the layout manager is null and not BorderLayout as he said

Comment: @kleopatra this is an example learning code, the low quality are the out of scope answers and the "how dare you" mentality

Answer (score 3):

So your problem basically comes down to a misunderstanding over how layout management works in Swing.

To start with, take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) in particular, as this is the default layout manager user by `JFrame`

A simple fix would be to remove `setLayout(null)` and add your components as follows...

```
frame.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);      
frame.add(panel1);
```

But, your next question is going to be about why the size and position properties are ignored and that leads you straight back to the first link.

Layout managers are very powerful, but they can take some time to get use to.  You need to let go of the concept of "pixel perfect" layouts, as they tend to break really fast, as just about every environment your application runs on will have some level differences which will just haunt you.

Comment: setLayout(null) is used on `frame` everything works fine on the level of `frame`, the problem exists within `panel1` (even after affecting `FlowLayout` as its layout manager), so i dont understand what im not understanding here, `FlowLayout` doest work the same on containers inside other containers usind setLayout(null) ?

Comment: No - the problem is, you don't understand how the layout manager system works.  When you call `setVisible` on the frame, one of the things it's going to do is is run a layout pass, since the frame is still using a `BorderLayout` at this point, this will cause the last component added to be laid out - the other will be ignored and possibly set to `0x0` size. Changing the layout to `null` won't effect the last position/size the component was set to (by the layout manager) - best result is not to use `null` layouts - they aren't worth your time - learn the layout API instead

Comment: @vanguy I'd also be careful with setting the size of component based on the size of the window, as the viewable area is the window size MINUS the border insets.  Using the window size will have undesirable side effects

Answer (score 1):

remove the line

```
this.setLayout(null);
```

But the header is displayed below the panel.

My suggestion is to add a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) so you have control over where the components are displayed in the frame:

```
this.layout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

// when you add components to the frame, specify where you want them:
frame.add(header,BorderLayout.NORTH);      
frame.add(panel1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

For testing you can set a backgroundcolor to the panel to understand more how it is displayed:

```
panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
```